# More Timers fewer tasks or fewer timers with more tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

My question is the following. What is the better way, if I use more `Timers` with fewer tasks or I need define fewer `Timers` with more tasks? With which solution can I achive better performance?

Thank you!

Comment: No one can give you a good answer with only this info. What are you trying to do with the timers? What are the tasks?

Comment: If you want to know which _performs_ better, then test and profile. No one else can tell you, especially given the lack of an actual code example, but your own computer can.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! So my main task is develop an application what can continuously collect data from an other device via TCP (so my app is a TCP client) and at same time I collect data from database too. It is OK but all records which come from the database that I need scan according some conditions. 

So in this case I would like to know which is the better way fo me.

Comment: Maybe Parallel Job Consumer helps you: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31903/parallel-job-consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific scenario, you need to consider two things
1. Each timer will run in different thread.
2. Do you need more threads as compared to tasks or not?

Best practices can be as follows:

1. Use [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), so that you dont need to set frequency of each timer specially.

2. Define tasks as jobs and schedule them using cron-expressions.

3. Use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for async operations. TPL will allow to automatically create as much threads as you need (if your task is heavy). You can also use await-async to marshal your task on separate thread without stopping your main thread.